# Fastest and most efficient SQL query to check if UID exists

Tags: query, wpdb, meta-query, sql, customization

What's the fastest and most efficient way to check that a unique identifier exists in a database? Especially for an insanely large DB were you just want a `true/false` response to break when found.

```
global $wpdb;

$guid = '12345';

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE `uid`='$uid' LIMIT 1");

if( empty ( $results ) ){

   // OK to create

}
```

Is it also possible to limit these to a specific time period? Like no more than a month back? Ideally if I'm pulling in timestamped data is it possible to include that information in the query for a limited query. Limited being, no extra processing required beyond the required params.

I'm not sure quite yet how to profile queries so any insight is helpful. I've seen [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.sitepoint.com/explain-sql-explain-queries/) through google searches but I wouldn't know how to utilize this here.

Ultimate goal; can I add a new item (referenced by unique identifier) or does it already exist?

Comment: Why would you wanna check that? The GUID is composed of siteurl and post ID and is virtually impossible to duplicate under normal circumstances unless a database merge or other fishy business is involved.

Comment: @Zlatev - using 'uid' for this example in light of the confusion. It's any value in the DB on any table. Has more to do with external feed ingestion.